# Realtek UEFI UNDI Driver not loaded

Tags: networking, bios, uefi, edk2

I am developing efi application that should work with network.
I changed `EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi` file to efi shell to make starting efi shell on system start by default for convenience.
When shell starts I run command `ifconfig -l` to view available network interfaces settings.

And I faced the following behavior.

When system by default boots my shell (`EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi`), I don't see any network interfaces, running command `ifconfig -l`. But.
If I boot t same file (`EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi`) manually using (testing on HP Laptop)"boot menu/boot from file", shell starts and `ifconfig -l` shows network inteface `eth0`.

So, loading same efi file with default system boot or manually from boot menu gives me different results for network availability.

I decided to compare lists of loaded drivers in both cases and.
I noticed, that when system boots in default mode (not by manually specifying device from boot menu) driver `Realtek UEFI UNDI Driver` is absent. When I manually boot from file (`EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi`), it's loaded.

I think absence of this driver **'Realtek UEFI UNDI Driver'** is the reason. To check this I did following test:

1. downloaded from network Realtek UNDI driver (`RtkUndiDxe.efi`)
2. copied it to efi boot folder (`EFI\Boot\`)
3. booted into shell by system default boot and loaded Realter UNDI driver manually by command `load 'RtkUndiDxe.efi`
   As result, network interfaces appeared.

*Can somebody explain me, why by default system boot **Realtek UEFI UNDI Driver** is not loaded? Or how i can make system to load it's own `Realtek UEFI UNDI Driver` from my own efi app/driver?*

Comment: What commands are in your shells' `startup.nsh`?

Comment: I tested without startup.nsh. Only later added some echo prints there, nothing more.

Comment: `Startup.nsh` I not the reason, I think. Because, as I described, loading same device in different ways (by default boot or manually from boot menu) gives different results, although same shell and same `startup.nsh` files are loaded.

Comment: Some uefi systems implement a "Fast boot" mode. When this mode is activ not all drivers are loaded. Check your uefi menu for such a setting.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In "Fast boot" mode some drivers are not loaded. So, next question: How I can load them by myself in this case from my efi app or driver?

Comment: Or maybe by shell

Comment: You can use the LoadImage and StartImage functions inside EFI_BOOT_SERVICE (gBS). You must provide the correct device path to the LoadImage function, you have to search the correct firmware file first using the EFI_FIRMWARE_VOLUME2_PROTOCOL protocol.

Comment: MiSimon, I've tried to load drivers, according to your advice, using EFI_FIRMWARE_VOLUME2_PROTOCOL, like that
Status = gBS->LocateHandleBuffer(...&gEfiFirmwareVolume2ProtocolGuid...
...
Status = gBS->HandleProtocol(...&gEfiFirmwareVolume2ProtocolGuid...
...
NextStatus = Fv->GetNextFile(Fv, Key, &FileType, &NameGuid, &Attribute...;
...
Status = Fv->ReadSection(...EFI_SECTION_USER_INTERFACE
...
DevicePath = FvFileDevicePath(Buffer[Index], &NameGuid);
...
Status = gBS->LoadImage(FALSE, gImageHandle, DevicePath, NULL, 0, &ImageHandle);
...
Status = gBS->StartImage(ImageHandle

Comment: And it works, I loaded some drivers in this way, but Realtek UNDI driver and other UNDI drivers were not among them. Am I missing something?

Comment: It could also be stored inside a PCI option ROM (Specification 2.9, Chapter 14.4.2 PCI Option ROMs). When i run the "drivers" command in the efi shell is get the source of the image, in my case the Relatek UEFI Undi Driver was loaded from FV(xxxx)/FvFile(xxxx), what is the source of the driver on your system?

Comment: You were right! I didn't find Realtek UEFI Undi Driver by mistake, but it was there among other files, as you said. Thank you for your advice, I highly appreciate it!!!

Comment: @AlexNemkovich, do you have steps you try on the RtkUndiDxe.efi?  How you get the RtkUndiDxe.efi to auto load into the UEFI shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some drivers are not loaded in **"Fast boot"** option in BIOS. When I turned it off, now network drivers and some others are loaded.

But also you can load needed drivers even with **"Fast boot"** option turned on on your own, using **EFI Firmware Volume2 Protocol** as said MiSimon in comments to my question.

> You can use the **LoadImage** and **StartImage** functions inside
> EFI_BOOT_SERVICE (gBS). You must provide the correct device path to
> the LoadImage function, you have to search the correct firmware file
> first using the **EFI_FIRMWARE_VOLUME2_PROTOCOL** protocol.

Below is sample of code (without error handling and other stuff), that enumerates firmware driver files and loads them to memory.

```
... Status = gBS->LocateHandleBuffer(ByProtocol, &gEfiFirmwareVolume2ProtocolGuid, NULL, &NoFvHandles, &FvHandleList);
... Status = gBS->HandleProtocol(FvHandleList[Index], &gEfiFirmwareVolume2ProtocolGuid, (VOID **)&Fv); 
... NextStatus = Fv->GetNextFile(Fv, Key, &FileType, &NameGuid, &Attributes, &FileSize); 
... Status = Fv->ReadSection(Fv, &NameGuid, EFI_SECTION_USER_INTERFACE ...
... DevicePath = FvFileDevicePath(FvHandleList[Index], &NameGuid); 
... Status = gBS->LoadImage(FALSE, gImageHandle, DevicePath, NULL, 0, &ImageHandle); 
... Status = gBS->StartImage(ImageHandle ...
```